# Error Messages with form_tag in separate controller Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I used a form_tag to access an action from a different controller in one of my Rails views. This has caused trouble for me rendering the error message. I am also using JQuery which could potentially be causing an issue. I have read that form_tag is not bound to a model, so that might mean that something like validates_uniqueness_of might not work. Would appreciate help understanding validations with form_tag!

For reference, here is my controller:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.new
  @post.text = params[:text]
  @post.user_id = current_user.id
  @post.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to(username_path(:username => current_user)) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And my view (on my User model)

```
    
# app/views/users/show.html
<% form_tag({:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :method => "post", :class => 'newpost') do %>
  <%= error_messages_for :post  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :text, params[:text] %>
  <%= image_submit_tag("../images/add.png", :border => 0, :class => "submitadd") %>
%lt;% end %>
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: the server output shows the message post, but then no error message is being returned. When the input matches the validation, the post works, when it doesn't nothing happens in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that might be that you are double saving and somehow clearing some error messages.  You could try the following instead:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.new
  @post.text = params[:text]
  @post.user_id = current_user.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to(username_path(:username => current_user)) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

After calling render :action => 'new' you should be able to view the error messages with:

```
<%= error_messages_for @post  %>
```

You can verify that there are errors by displaying @post.errors in your log as well.

Comment: I am still not seeing anything come through on my server output. It is as if the format.html {render :action => "new"} is not doing anything. I tried render @post.error and it looks like an error is being passed through to my server output, but I am not sure how to access it in my view.

Comment: I updated my answer with that information as well. The render :action => 'new' is correct.

Comment: Working from the console when i try to save something that cannot be validated I get false for @post.save. Then calling @post.errors returns an error message. I am using Jquery to submit the form - and regardless of what I do, POST shows on my server output. rendered posts/new.html.erb is also showing at the end of the server output after the POST, so I am not sure why the error messages are not showing with it. Thanks a ton for helping!

Comment: So are you redirecting the user after the POST request or is it an AJAX call?  You don't have a format.js call if the save doesn't succeed in your code.  How are you handling the AJAX response?

Comment: Ahhhh - My mistake. I wasn't dealing with it. Thanks for the help here. When I turn off AJAX it works perfect.